# loading xml data into table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an XML as below. and I am trying to load that xml to a SQL Server table using t-sql code:
XML:

```
<Validations>
    <Validation>
    <validation id="ActivityIdPass" status="Fail">An Activity ID must be defined.</validation>
    <validation id="ActivityFormatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    <validation id="ActivityFormatSubCatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    <validation id="StartDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Release Date must be defined</validation>
    <validation id="EndDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Expiration Date must be defined.</validation>
    <validation id="CityPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    <validation id="State" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    </Validation>
</Validations>
```

and I am trying to get the output below when loaded into table:

[image: image2]

can anybody help me out.

Comment: Google 'Load XML data into SQL Server 2012'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OPENXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186918.aspx).

Following [Arshad Ali's](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/) example:

> Process XML data using OPENXML function
>
> Now as I said before, XML data stored in a column of data type XML can
>   be processed either by using XML functions available in SQL Server or
>   by using the sp_xml_preparedocument stored procedure along with the
>   OPENXML function.
>
> We will first call the sp_xml_preparedocument stored procedure by
>   specifying the XML data which will then output the handle of the XML
>   data that it has prepared and stored in internal cache.
>
> Then we will use the handle returned by the sp_xml_preparedocument
>   stored procedure in the OPENXML function to open the XML data and read
>   it.
>
> Note: the sp_xml_preparedocument stored procedure stores the XML data
>   in SQL Server's internal cache, it is essential to release this stored
>   XML data from internal cache by calling the sp_xml_removedocument
>   stored procedure. We should call the sp_xml_removedocument stored
>   procedure as early possible, so that internal cache can be freed for
>   other usage.

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, Address
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer')
WITH 
(
CustomerID [varchar](50) '@CustomerID',
CustomerName [varchar](100) '@CustomerName',
Address [varchar](100) 'Address'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, so, I hope this will help you:

```
DECLARE @idoc int, @doc nvarchar(max); 
SET @doc ='
<Validations>
    <Validation>
        <validation id="ActivityIdPass" status="Fail">An Activity ID must be defined.</validation>
        <validation id="ActivityFormatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="ActivityFormatSubCatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="StartDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Release Date must be defined</validation>
        <validation id="EndDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Expiration Date must be defined</validation>
        <validation id="CityPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="State" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    </Validation>
</Validations>'; 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc; 

select ActivityIdPass, ActivityFormatPass, ActivityFormatSubCatPass, StartDateTimePass, EndDateTimePass, CityPass, [State]
from
(
SELECT id,val_id,val_text
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Validations/Validation/validation',2) 
         WITH (id       int          '@mp:parentid', 
               val_id   nvarchar(50) '@id', 
               val_text nvarchar(50)  '.')
) d
pivot
(
  max(val_text)
  for val_id in (ActivityIdPass, ActivityFormatPass, ActivityFormatSubCatPass, StartDateTimePass, EndDateTimePass, CityPass, [State])
) piv;

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet does it using XQuery.

- Using [`XML.nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to gather the `Validations/Validation` nodes using an XQuery
- Using [`XML.value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the value from the `<validation></validation>` elements

```
DECLARE @inp XML='
<Validations>
    <Validation>
        <validation id="ActivityIdPass" status="Fail">An Activity ID must be defined.</validation>
        <validation id="ActivityFormatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="ActivityFormatSubCatPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="StartDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Release Date must be defined</validation>
        <validation id="EndDateTimePass" status="Fail">A Expiration Date must be defined.</validation>
        <validation id="CityPass" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
        <validation id="State" status="Pass">Passed</validation>
    </Validation>
</Validations>';

SELECT
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="ActivityIdPass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS ActivityIdPass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="ActivityFormatPass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS ActivityFormatPass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="ActivityFormatSubCatPass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS ActivityFormatSubCatPass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="StartDateTimePass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS StartDateTimePass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="EndDateTimePass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS EndDateTimePass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="CityPass"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS CityPass,
    n.v.value('(validation[@id="State"])[1]','NVARCHAR(128)') AS State
FROM
    @inp.nodes('/Validations/Validation') AS n(v);
```

---

Result:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------+--------+
|         ActivityIdPass          | ActivityFormatPass | ActivityFormatSubCatPass |       StartDateTimePass        |          EndDateTimePass           | CityPass | State  |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------+--------+
| An Activity ID must be defined. | Passed             | Passed                   | A Release Date must be defined | A Expiration Date must be defined. | Passed   | Passed |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------+--------+
```